# Short story about lawyers fighting cases through hallucinogens

Tags: story-identification, laws, drug

I recall this strange little gem of a story that I read years ago:
It opens with two opposing lawyers amicably greeting, then one is asked to choose the drug to be used.  They are both dosed with a hallucinogen, then hooked up to a computer.  It gets very surreal after that, as they try their cases directly via their drugged brains. Unfortunately I don't remember the details.  I believe it is from the 60's or so.  For some reason I associate it with Harlan Ellison, but it might have been from a collection he edited.  I have most of his books but cannot find it.

Does anyone know this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Stoned Counsel by H. H. Hollis](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42223).

> Not for the first time, the lawyer muttered to himself, "There must be an easier way to earn a living." With a grimace, he felt the grief case in his inside jacket pocket, then in an excess of caution pulled it out and flipped it open to be sure it was packed with a full range of hallucinogens. Two weeks before, he had come without scopolamine and had to take a shot from his opponent's case. The memory shuddered in his head. "Bastard had that scop doctored with LSD, I know he did."

It's from the Anthology Again Dangerous Visions edited by Harlan Ellison, hence the connection to Ellison you remember.

Comment: Thank you! I have that book. I am going to go read it now.